# Dgrid - rowIndex in OnDemandGrid

Tags: dojo, dgrid

I am using OnDemandGrid virtuall scrolling with JSONRest store.

```
         require([
        "dojo/request",
        "dojo/store/Memory",
        "dgrid/OnDemandGrid",
        "dojo/store/JsonRest"
                    ], function (request, Memory, OnDemandGrid,JsonRest) {

            var jsonstore = new JsonRest({target: url , idProperty: "id"});

            // Create an instance of OnDemandGrid referencing the store
            var grid = new OnDemandGrid({

                store: jsonstore,
                columns: Layout,
                minRowsPerPage : 40,
                maxRowsPerPage : 40,
                loadingMessage: "Loading data...",
                noDataMessage: "No results found."
            }, "grid");

            grid.startup();

    });
```

I dont know how to get the rowIndex of the cell.
Can someone tell me how to find the row index?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking?  Which rowIndex/cell are you talking about?  Is it one that has been selected in the grid or are you looking for something that will tell you the row index of a particular record in the whole store vs the row index of what is displayed at any given time on your grid?

Comment: Like rowIndex in dojox.EnhancedGrid formatter function ,do we have anything in Dgrid?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything in dGrid (or OnDemandGrid) which will give you a specific row index, but see my "answer" below to see if that helps you find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You may find what you're looking for by using `Selection` mixin provided by dGrid.  Using `Selection`, you can  define your grid like this:

```
            grid = new (declare([OnDemandGrid, Selection]))({
                store: Observable(Memory({ // replace with your store of choice
                    idProperty: 'id'
                })),
                columns: { /* your columns layout */ },
                noDataMessage: 'No results found.',
                loadingMessage: 'Loading data...'
            });
            grid.startup();
```

In your columns object, you can define a column that uses a function called `renderCell` that looks like this:

```
            renderCell: function (object, value, node, options) {
                // Object is the row; i.e., object's properties are the column names
                // value is the value for this cell 
                // node is the DOM node of this cell
                // Not sure what 'options' refers to
            }
```

When a row is selected, you can retrieve the row by using the `grid.selection` property, which is an object that contains key/value pairs where the the ID's (based on `idProperty`) are the keys.  The value for each key contains a boolean that indicates whether or not that particular row is selected.  So, to get each selected row, you could do something like:

```
            for (selectedId in selection) {
                if (selection.hasOwnProperty(selectedId) && selection[selectedId] === true) {
                    var selectedRow = grid.row(selection[selectedId];

                    ... // and so on...
                }
            }
```

None of this specifically gives you the row index, but you may be able to figure it out from here using your browser's Development Tools (e.g., Firebug for Firefox, etc).